# Changing from Singleton to Prototype with @Scope("prototype")

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want /dog2 to be different object but i still have no idea why @Scope("prorotype") is not working for me. I tried with another Scopes but still there is the same problem - i go to /dog then to /dog2 and i see on both "Sharo" instead to see "null" on /dog2

SpringProjectApplication.java

```
package com.example.demo.springproject;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ScopedProxyMode;

import com.example.demo.springproject.entities.Animal;
import com.example.demo.springproject.entities.Dog;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringprojectApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringprojectApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Scope("prototype")
    @Bean
    public Animal getDog() {
        return new Dog();
    }
}
```

AnimalController.java

```
package com.example.demo.springproject.controllers;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import com.example.demo.springproject.entities.Animal;

@Controller
public class AnimalController {

@Autowired
private Animal dog;

@GetMapping("/dog2")
@ResponseBody
public String getDog() {
    if (dog.getName() == null) {
        return "null";
    }
    return dog.getName();
}

}
```

DogController.java

```
package com.example.demo.springproject.controllers;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import com.example.demo.springproject.entities.Animal;

@Controller
public class DogController {

@Autowired
private Animal dog;

@GetMapping("/dog")
@ResponseBody
public String getHomePage() {
    dog.setName("Sharo");
    return dog.getName();
}
}
```

EDIT:
Dog.java

```
package com.example.demo.springproject.entities;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Dog implements Animal {

private String name;

public Dog() {

}

@Override
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

@Override
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

}
```

Comment: Did you really write it `prorotype`?

Comment: Yes in the same exact way, why ? Oh I saw it ... i just changed it  in too many ways and at the end i guess i typed it wrong ... this is not the problem.

Comment: Do you see anything wrong ?

Comment: What does the `Dog` class look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using both `@Bean` and `@Component` annotations for `Dog`, when you should be choosing one or the other. Either remove the `@Bean` and add `@Scope` to `Dog` class, or remove the `@Component` annotation from the class.

Comment: Thank you very much. I just wanted to ask you to make another comment so i can mark it. Saved my day !

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a syntax error.
try

`@Scope("prototype")` instead

If this doesn't resolve your issue, please share your animal and dog classes.

Answer (score -1):

Controllers in SpringMVC are singletons. Between multiple requests your class variable get shared. You can try @Scope("request") annotation above your controller class.